# Sum items in core data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have price attribute saved in the array as String and i want to sum all the price

```
     if let fdf = cart.price{
        fdf.toInt()
    }
```

But it is not working

Answer (score 1):

Use like as below.Based on your swift version choose it.

```
var totalCount = 0;

                for i in 1...10 { 

//                Swift 1.x
                    let myString: String = "256"
                    let myInt: Int? = myString.toInt()
                    totalCount = totalCount + myInt! 

//                Swift 2.x
                    let myString: String = "256"
                    let myInt: Int? = Int(myString)
                    totalCount = totalCount + myInt!

                }
```

Try this way

```
for i in 1...10 {

                // Swift 1.x
                let myString: String = "256"


                if let number = myString.toInt() {
                    let myNumber = NSNumber(integer:number)
                    totalCount = totalCount + myNumber.integerValue
                    print(totalCount)
                } else {
                    print("'\(myString)' did not convert to an Int")
                }


                // Swift 2.x
                let myString: String = "256"
                let myInt: Int? = Int(myString)
                if let number = Int(myString) {
                    let myNumber = NSNumber(integer:number)
                    totalCount = totalCount + myNumber.integerValue
                    print(totalCount)
                } else {
                    print("'\(myString)' did not convert to an Int")
                }



            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will add all of your price attributes together

```
var total = yourArray.reduce(0) { (a, b) in a + Int(b.price) }
```